# Whats the difference between ConnectTimeout and ServerAliveInterval in ssh

Tags: unix, ssh

I am doing ssh on several remote servers, Some of the servers doesn't respond and some of them might be down.

To preclude such scenarios I used `ConnectTimeout` in ssh command. It was timing out as I configured It to be.

My current way of doing `ssh`

```
ssh -o LogLevel=Error -oConnectTimeout=5 -oBatchMode=yes -l becomeaccount servername './command.sh'
```

All was going good until one day when I found a stale ssh connection on one of my server. It was on for more than 3 days.

So now I think I might have missed something, I tried to google it and found there is something called as `ServerAliveInterval`...would that solve my problem? how is it different than `ConnectTimeOut` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "ServerAliveInterval" specifies a periodic polling time between the SSH server and client.  The intent is twofold:

(1) To close down idle ssh sessions where either
  [a] one side or the other crashes hard (i.e.: machine failure/poweroff)
  [b] one side or the other changes IP addresses

(2) To MAINTAIN idle ssh sessions over a NAT that would tear down (or terminate) idle TCP sessions

ServerAliveInterval affects the "ssh" client. There's a corresponding parameter for the "sshd" server. (There is also a TCPKeepAlive option too.)  If you're seeing orphaned sshd sessions on your remote servers, you should consider making appropriate changes in the remote servers's sshd_config.  If you can't implement changes in the remote server's sshd_config but still need to have idle logins die, check to see if your shell has an idle-timeout ("bash" does.)